# Python 3.4 can't find OpenSSL

Tags: python, websocket, openssl, wss

I trying to use WebSockets in Python 3.4 (Windows 7)
This is a test code:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientFactory, WebSocketClientProtocol, connectWS
import json

class ClientProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):
    def onConnect(self, response):
        print("Server connected: {0}".format(response.peer))
    def initMessage(self):
        message_data = [{"type": "subscribe", "product_id": "BTC-USD"}]
        message_json = json.dumps(message_data)
        print("sendMessage: " + message_json)
        self.sendMessage(message_json)
    def onOpen(self):
        print("onOpen calls initMessage()")
        self.initMessage()
    def onMessage(self, msg, binary):
        print("Got echo: " + msg)
    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    factory = WebSocketClientFactory("wss://ws-feed.exchange.coinbase.com")
    factory.protocol = ClientProtocol
    connectWS(factory)
    reactor.run()
```

When I start it I have an error:

```
F:\python>wss.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\python\wss.py", line 24, in <module>
    connectWS(factory)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\autobahn-0.11.0-py3
.5.egg\autobahn\twisted\websocket.py", line 519, in connectWS
    from twisted.internet import ssl
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\twisted-15.5.0-py3.
5.egg\twisted\internet\ssl.py", line 59, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import SSL
ImportError: No module named 'OpenSSL'
```

But when I tryed to install the OpenSSL, an error appeared:

```
F:\python>easy_install openssl
Searching for openssl
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/openssl/
Couldn't find index page for 'openssl' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for openssl
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('openssl')
```

How can I start this test code?

Answer (score 5):

Try to install pyOpenSSL package: `pip install pyOpenSSL`